# -(void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController not been called

Tags: ios, objective-c, dismiss

As in the title, I do not manage to have that callback called in order to dismiss the game center view controller neither on my iOS 7 iPhone nor iOS 8 iPad. This is the code I use:

```
GKGameCenterViewController *controller=nil;

- (IBAction)achievementButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    if (!controller){
        controller=[[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
        controller.delegate=self;
    }
    NSLog(@"controller=%@", controller);
    if (controller) [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController{
    [gameCenterViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

   // I also tried [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil] but anyway the function seems to not even enter here
}
```

If I take the function off, the delegate complaints it is missing, so the issue should not be connected to that. What might that be and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that I used:

```
    controller.delegate=self;
```

omitting:

```
    controller.gameCenterDelegate = self;
```

Once inserted the latter, the view controller dismisses without problems, both when I manually present the controller and when it is shown to login her. I really wonder why that beast has too delegates, if not to confuse developers...